# Change sheet name inside formula by changing static sheet value

Tags: excel-2007

=IF(ROWS(E$10:E10)<=$C$6,INDEX(Sheet4!B$2:B$200,SMALL(IF(Sheet4!$A$2:$A$200="Sprint-1",ROW(Sheet4!$B$2:$B$200)-ROW(Sheet4!$B$2)+1),ROWS(E$10:E10))),"")

This is my formula, i would like to change the static value "sheet4!" with my dynamic value which i will enter in cell "C4".

Answer (score 0):

Indirect() will do it for you.

Your Current Reference

> Sheet4!$A$2:$A$200

Change it as

```
=INDIRECT('"&C4&"'!$A$2:$A$200)
```

Like the above change rest of your references.

**Caution:**
Indirect() is a volatile function which recalculates on any change.